# Split up two byte char into two single byte chars

Tags: c, char

I have a char of value say 0xB3, and I need to split this into two separate char's.  So X = 0xB and Y = 0x3.  I've tried the following code:

```
int main ()
{
    char addr = 0xB3;
    char *p = &addr;

    printf ("%c, %c\n", p[0], p[1]);          //This prints ?, Y
    printf ("%X, %X\n", p[0], p[1]);          //This prints FFFFFFB3, 59

    return 0;
}
```

Just to clarify, I need to take any 2 byte char of value 00 to FF and split the first and second byte into separate char's.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have 4-bit characters?

Comment: yes, i would recommend you learn the meaning of common terminology like 'byte' - its not necessary to do your job, but helpful when interacting with the community

Comment: Just FYI. 1 or a 0 is a bit, 4 bits in a nibble, 2 nibbles (8 bits) in a byte. `0xB3` is a single byte, 10110011 are the bits. So you want the upper nibble seperated from the lower one.

Answer (score 5):

Straight from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble):

```
#define HI_NIBBLE(b) (((b) >> 4) & 0x0F)
#define LO_NIBBLE(b) ((b) & 0x0F)
```

So `HI_NIBBLE(addr)` would be `0xB`. However, `0x00` through `0xFF` are not "double bytes". They're single-byte values. A single hex digit can take on 16 bytes, while a byte can take on 256 = 16² of them, so you need two hex digits to represent arbitrary byte values.

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few problems here, let's take a look at your code:

```
int main ()
{
    char addr = 0xB3;  <-- you're asigning 0xB3 in hex, which is (179 in dec) to addr
    char *p = &addr;   <-- you're assigning a pointer to point to addr
```

If `addr` were unsigned, it would now be set to 179, the [extended ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) of `│ ( Box drawing character )`

A `char` value can be -127 to +127 if it's signed, or 0 to 255 if it's unsigned. Here (according to your output) it's signed, so you're overflowing the `char` with that assignment.

```
printf ("%c, %c\n", p[0], p[1]); <-- print the char value of what p is pointing to
                                     also, do some UB
printf ("%X, %X\n", p[0], p[1]); <-- print the hex value of  what p is pointing to
                                     also, do some UB
```

So the second part of your code here prints the char value of your overflowed `addr` var, which happens to print `'?'` for you. The hex value of `addr` is `FFFFFFB3` indicating you have a negitive value (upper most bit is the signed bit).

This: `p[0]` is really an "add and deference" operator. Meaning that we're going to take the address of `p`, add `0` to it, then deference and look at the result:

```
p ---------+
           V
       ------------------------------------------
      | ptr(0xB3) |    ?      |     ?     | ... |
      -------------------------------------------
       0xbfd56c2b  0xbfd56c2C  0xbfd56c2d   ...
```

When you do `p[1]` this goes one `char` or one byte past ptr and gives you that result. What's there? Don't know. That's out of your scope:

```
p+1 -------------------+
                       V
       ------------------------------------------
      | ptr(0xB3) |    ?      |     ?     | ... |
      -------------------------------------------
       0xbfd56c2b  0xbfd56c2C  0xbfd56c2d   ...
```

`Y`'s ASCII value (in hex) is 0x59, so behind your pointer in memory was a `Y`. But it could have been anything, what is was going to do was undefined. A correct way to do this would be:

```
int main ()
{
    unsigned char addr = 0xB3;
    char low = addr & 0x0F;
    char high = (addr >> 4) & 0x0F;

    printf("%#x becomes %#x and %#x\n", addr, high, low);

    return 0;
}
```

This works via:

```
    0xB3  =>  1011 0011        0xB3 >> 4 =   0000 1011
            & 0000 1111                    & 0000 1111
            ------------                  -------------
              0000 0011 => 3 low             0000 1011 => B high
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to pass by a pointer? just take the 4 relevant bits and shift the most significative when needed:

```
char lower = value & 0x0F;
char higher = (value >> 4) & 0x0F;
```

Then `0xB3` is a single byte, not two bytes. Since a hex digit can have 16 values two digits can store 16*16 = 256 values, which is how much you can store in a byte.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so your trying to split 0xB3 into 0xB and 0x3, Just for future reference don't say 'byte chars', The 2 parts of a byte are commonly known as 'Nibbles', a byte is made up of 2 nibbles (which are made up of 4 bits).
If you didn't know, `char` refers to 1 byte.

So heres the problems with your code:

```
char addr = 0xB3;  <---- Creates single byte with value 0xB3 - Good
char *p = &addr;   <---- Creates pointer pointing to 0xB3 - Good

printf ("%c, %c\n", p[0], p[1]); <---- p[0], p[1] - Bad
printf ("%X, %X\n", p[0], p[1]); <---- p[0], p[1] - Bad
```

Ok so when your referring to `p[0]` and `p[1]` your telling your system that the pointer `p` is pointing to an array of `char`s (p[0] would refer to 0xB3 but p[1] would be going to the next byte in memory)

Example : This is something your system memory would look like (But with 8 byte pointers)

```
     Integer Values Area              Pointers Area
0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06    0x12 0x13 0x14 0x15 0x16
-----------------------------    ------------------------
.... .... 0xB3 0x59 .... ....    .... .... 0x03 .... ....
-----------------------------    ------------------------
           ^    ^                           ^
          addr  |                           p (example pointer pointing to example address 0x03)
             Random number                    (Pointers are normally 8 Bytes but)
             showing up in p[1]               (But In this example I used single bytes)
```

So when you tell your system to get `p[0]` or `*p` (these would do the same thing) 
it will go to the address (eg. 0x03) and get one byte (because its a char)
in this case `0xB3`.
But when you try `p[1]` or `*(p+1)` That will go to the address (eg. 0x03) skip the first `char` and get the next one giving us `0x59` which would be there for some other variable.

Ok so we've got that out of the way so how do you get the nibbles?

A problem with getting the nibble is that you generally can't just have half a byte a put variable, theres no type that supports just 4 bits.
When you print with %x/%X it will only show the nibbles up to the last non-zero number eg. = 0x00230242 would only show 230242 but if you do something like

%2lX would show 2 full bytes (including the zeros)
%4lX would show 4 full bytes (including the zeros)

So it is pretty pointless trying to get individual nibbles but if you want way to do something like then do:

```
char addr = 0x3B;
char addr1 = ((addr >> 4) & 0x0F);
char addr2 = ((addr >> 0) & 0x0F);
```